# Plot Integral with variable limits in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, plot, limit, integral

I'm having some trouble trying to solve and plot an integral in matlab. In fact, I know that if a solve one, I'll solve all the integrals that I need now.

I have plot in x axis a value of a variable "d" and in y axis the value of a integral of a normalized gaussian function from -inf to ((40*log10(d)-112)/36) and I'm not finding out a way to do it correctly. D is between 0 and 1600

Can anybody here please help me?

Comment: Perhaps showing your tentative code would be helpful. Also, the integral of a Gaussian is a [complementary error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: the problem about using (1/2) error function is that somewhere in this function it'll cross the middle of the gaussian (but you helped me to think it better, now a have a new ideia, thanks a lot!)

Comment: for now, my tentative code to calculate it is:

for d = 10:10:1590;
b = (1/((2*pi)^(1/2))).*int((exp(-((x).^2)/2)),-inf,((40*log10(d)-112)/36)); %(23)
end

and then even if it's right (it might be), I'm not achieving to plot it in the way I want.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab you can use the integral-function to evaluate integrals:

```
q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax)
```

fun needs to be a function handle, also called *function functions*, like these two examples:

```
square = @(x) x.^2;
plusone = @(x) x+1;
```

Comment: And it's done. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.
<h1>
syms x;

for d = 10:10:1590; %Loop for between 10 and 1590
b(d) = (1/((2*pi)^(1/2))).*int((exp(-((x).^2)/2)),-inf,((40*log10(d)-112)/6));

stem(b,'b')
<h1>

It's simplier than it seems to be before geting it right. Sorry for the format of this post, I'm new here and I'm trying to learn how this works, too.

end